# Update email address and profile on SandboxPostCopy MIXED DML OPERATION error

Tags: apex, sandbox, sandboxpostcopy, mixed-dml

I've been trying to update user emails and profiles after a sandbox is created and using the SandboxPostCopy interface. However I keep running into the below error:

```
   Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id xxxxxxxxxxxx; 
    first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted
    after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa):
```

I know that I have to have a future job to get around this but has anyone successfully managed to not use an asynchronous job?

Comment: What else are you doing in your SandboxPostCopy? I usually utilize a [queuable class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) to handle my user updates related to this, as it's my last step and I don't need it to be done in any specific timing/order. As mentioned, you can use a [future method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm) to handle it async as well as long as you don't depend on those updates to finish to do downstream logic in the sandbox refresh script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm updating just custom settings other than user, so I don't see why I'm getting the Mixed DML error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm) has a list of the sObjects that cannot be used together in DML Operations that is useful.

As you can see, `Custom Setting` and `User` is on there which is why you run into the issue.

There's also a [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315345&type=1&mode=1) from Salesforce regarding this error message that lets you know the issue is when there's multiple updates on the listed sobjects in the **same transaction**

If the user update is not something you need to wait to finish for to do other logic, you can simply move that code into its own `@future` method which would perform the update in an asynchronous update (not the same transaction) which would *avoid* the exception.

```
public without sharing class SandboxRefreshScript implements SandboxPostCopy {
    public void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        //move your user activation to another method
        activateUsers();
    }


    @Future
    private static void activateUsers() {
        //pull your users and perform the update here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! makes complete sense now :D